# hive order by in window function is too slow

Tags: sql, hive, window-functions

table structure like

```
department  person  date  sales
dep1         alice   0     10
dep1         alice   1     20
dep1         bob     0     20
dep1         bob     1     40
dep1         bob     2     50
```

sql like

```
SELECT department, person, date, sum(value) 
AS sales_sofar over(PARTITION BY dim1,dim2 
ORDER BY date)
```

when I run it in spark sql or remove the window function and run in hive,it only takes like 2 miniutes,but when i run the whole sql in hive it takes more than an hour and seems stuck in a reduce and have no progress,so I inspect the reduce and there is only 1 reducer,I thought maybe because of the order by clause so I also tried
`select sum(value) over w1 window w1 as(distribute by dim1,dim2 sort by index)`,but it is the same.I tried params like `mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize`,it is a little better but still very slow.My question is:why is it so slow and why distribute by cluase not work and there is still only one reducer?

Comment: Have you tried using tez engine parameter. Can you show your expected output?

Comment: Table statistics present? Does Hive have a way to guess how many reducers it should allocate, based on key cardinalities? Failing that, did you try setting a hard value for number of reducers (standard MapReduce property, via `SET` command in Hive script)?